# how to trigger click event without button in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having the following code for typescript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { CoreConfig } from '@services/config';
import { CoreUtils } from '@services/utils/utils';
import { CoreLoginHelperProvider } from '@features/login/services/login-helper';
import { ModalController } from '@singletons';

/**
 * Component that displays onboarding help regarding the CoreLoginSitePage.
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'core-login-site-onboarding',
    templateUrl: 'site-onboarding.html',
    styleUrls: ['site-onboarding.scss', '../../login.scss'],
})
export class CoreLoginSiteOnboardingComponent {

    step = 0;

    /**
     * Go to next step.
     *
     * @param e Click event.
     */
    next(e: Event): void {
        e.stopPropagation();

        this.step++;
    }

    /**
     * Go to previous step.
     *
     * @param e Click event.
     */
    previous(e: Event): void {
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (this.step == 0) {
            ModalController.dismiss();
        } else {
            this.step--;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close modal.
     *
     * @param e Click event.
     */
    skip(e: Event): void {
        e.stopPropagation();

        this.saveOnboardingDone();
        ModalController.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Create a site.
     *
     * @param e Click event.
     */
    gotoWeb(e: Event): void {
        e.stopPropagation();

        this.saveOnboardingDone();

        CoreUtils.openInBrowser('https://moodle.com/getstarted/', { showBrowserWarning: false });

        ModalController.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Saves the onboarding has finished.
     */
    protected saveOnboardingDone(): void {
        CoreConfig.set(CoreLoginHelperProvider.ONBOARDING_DONE, 1);
    }

}
```

and this is the HTML code

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="previous($event)" [attr.aria-label]="'core.back' | translate">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="fas-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title></ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="skip($event)" [attr.aria-label]="'core.skip' | translate">
                {{'core.skip' | translate}}
            </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
    <div>
        <div class="ion-text-center ion-padding core-login-site-logo">
            <img src="assets/img/login_logo.png" class="avatar-full login-logo" role="presentation" alt="">
        </div>

        <h3 class="core-login-onboarding-step">
            {{'core.login.onboardingwelcome' | translate}}
        </h3>

        <div *ngIf="step == 0" class="core-login-onboarding-step">
            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="skip($event)" class="ion-margin-bottom" fill="outline">
                {{'core.login.onboardingimalearner' | translate}}
            </ion-button>
            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="next($event)" class="ion-margin-bottom" fill="outline">
                {{'core.login.onboardingimaneducator' | translate}}
            </ion-button>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="step == 1" class="core-login-onboarding-step">
            <p class="core-login-onboarding-text">
                {{ 'core.login.onboardingtoconnect' | translate }}
            </p>
            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="skip($event)" class="ion-margin-bottom" fill="outline">
                {{ 'core.login.onboardingialreadyhaveasite' | translate }}
            </ion-button>
            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="next($event)" class="ion-margin-bottom">
                {{ 'core.login.onboardingineedasite' | translate }}
            </ion-button>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="step == 2" class="core-login-onboarding-step">
            <ul class="core-login-onboarding-text ion-text-start">
                <li>
                    <ion-icon name="far-check-circle" aria-hidden="true">
                    </ion-icon> {{ 'core.login.onboardingcreatemanagecourses' | translate }}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ion-icon name="far-check-circle" aria-hidden="true">
                    </ion-icon> {{ 'core.login.onboardingenrolmanagestudents' | translate }}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ion-icon name="far-check-circle" aria-hidden="true">
                    </ion-icon> {{ 'core.login.onboardingprovidefeedback' | translate }}
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ion-button expand="block" (click)="gotoWeb($event)" class="ion-margin-bottom">
                {{ 'core.login.onboardinggetstarted' | translate }}
            </ion-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I want to skip this page by calling skip method in the top of the class without click on the button

how to do that ?

Comment: Make the event in `skip` method optionnal by testing the existence before calling `stopPropagation`, or create a new `Event` object to pass as a parameter?

Comment: @Kaddath actually I do not have any experience in ionic so could you please help me and tell me where to call the skip method, I have added it in different locations in the file to be called before showing the screen, but it keeps give me error messages

Comment: Maybe if you could add what you have tried to the question and what was the error would help a litlle, the more I think about it the more it seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). To call `skip` in the class itself may not assure it will be before the page is shown, it would be better not to to open the modal in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Kaddath change your skip method definition like below

```
/**
     * Close modal.
     *
     * @param e Click event.
     */
    skip(e: Event = null): void {
      if(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
      }

        this.saveOnboardingDone();
        ModalController.dismiss();
    }
```

And in the class constructor which will be the first method to be executed you need to call skip method.

```
constructor(){
 this.skip();
}
```

Hope this will help you.